# Autofac - Resolve specific implementation from registered assembly

Tags: vb.net, autofac

I'm using Autofac and want to resolve the correct implementation of the current assembly

I have a DataContextFactory Interface and Class:

```
Public Interface IDataContextFactory
  Inherits IDisposable

  Function GetDataContext() As IDataContext

End Interface
```

and the Implementation of the Interface

```
Public Class CDataContextFactory
  Implements IDataContextFactory

  Private m_oDbContext As IDataContext

  Public Sub New(ByVal i_oDbContext As IDataContext)
    m_oDbContext = i_oDbContext
  End Sub

  Public Function GetDataContext() As CoreData.IDataContext Implements CoreData.IDataContextFactory.GetDataContext
    Return m_oDbContext
  End Function

End Class
```

So now I have in every registered assembly different IDataContext Implementations. For example I have an assembly called ReportData with the data context

```
Public Class CReportDataContext
  Inherits DbContext
  Implements IDataContext

    ---
End Class
```

And also one implementation inside an other Assembly CommonData

```
Public Class CFacadeDataContext
  Implements IDataContext

    ---
End Class
```

Then I have in every Assembly an implementation of my IRepository. For example

```
Public MustInherit Class CBaseReadRepository(Of T As {IEntity, Class})
  Implements IReadRepository(Of T)

  Private m_oDataContextFactory As IDataContextFactory
  Private m_oDataContext As IDataContext

  Protected ReadOnly m_oObjectDataSet As CQuery(Of T)

  Public Sub New(ByVal i_oDataContextFactory As IDataContextFactory)
    m_oDataContextFactory = i_oDataContextFactory
    m_oObjectDataSet = DataContext.ObjectDataSet(Of T)()
  End Sub

    ----
End Class
```

So how can I solve that the DataContextFactory will resolve the CReportDataContext inside the Assembly ReportData and the CFacadeDataContext inside the Assembly CommonData

Here is my ContainerBuilder registration:

```
Dim builder As New ContainerBuilder()

Dim oData = Assembly.Load("ReportData")
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(oData).Where(Function(t) t.Name.EndsWith("DataContext")).As(Of IDataContext) _
  .AsImplementedInterfaces.SingleInstance

oData = Assembly.Load("CommonData")
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(oData).Where(Function(t) t.Name.EndsWith("DataContext")) _
  .AsImplementedInterfaces().SingleInstance

builder.RegisterAdapter(Of IDataContext, IDataContextFactory)(Function(x) New CDataContextFactory(x))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autofac doesn't have built-in support for this sort of use case. Generally **it's recommended that you try not to tie specific implementations to consumers** because that breaks the whole IoC pattern - you may as well "new-up" the dependency type you need right in the class rather than injecting it.

If you *absolutely must* tie them together, you only have a couple of options. Neither is pretty, and both will require you to change the way you register things - you may not be able to do the `RegisterAssemblyTypes` assembly scanning like you do now.

First, **you could use named registrations**. When you register your `IDataContext`, you give it a name. When you register your consuming class, you tell the builder which named instance you expect to use.

```
builder.RegisterType<MyDataContext>().Named<IDataContext>("some-name");
var contextParam = ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<IDataContext>("some-name");
builder.RegisterType<MyConsumer>().As<IConsumer>().WithParameter(contextParam);
```

Second, **you could register an expression rather than a type** for the consumer:

```
builder.Register(c => new Consumer(new SomeContext())).As<IConsumer>();
```

Finally, **you could create a special module** that does the work of figuring out which assembly the consumer is coming from and try to match it to a corresponding `IDataContext`. This is more "automatic" but is a lot more complex. A stub might look like this:

```
public class DataContextModule : Autofac.Module
{
  protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(
    IComponentRegistry componentRegistry,
    IComponentRegistration registration)
  {
    registration.Preparing += OnComponentPreparing;
  }

  public static void OnComponentPreparing(object sender, PreparingEventArgs e)
  {
    Type typeBeingResolved = e.Component.Activator.LimitType;
    // TODO: Do some reflection to determine if the type takes an IDataContext
    // in the constructor. If it doesn't, bail. If it does...

    var parameter = new ResolvedParameter(
      (p, i) => p.ParameterType = typeof(IDataContext),
      (p, i) => {
        // TODO: Use i (the IComponentContext for the resolution)
        // to locate the right IDataContext from the list of registrations,
        // resolve that one, and return it so it can be used in
        // constructing the consumer object.
      });
  }
}
```

Like I said, not pretty.

If you have the ability to influence your design, it might be easier to make marker interfaces, like:

```
public interface ICoreDataContext : IDataContext { }
```

And then in your constructors take the specific interface:

```
public SomeClass(ICoreDataContext context);
```

That way type resolution would just work. (Marker interfaces aren't the greatest pattern in the world, either, but it's arguably better than tying individual implementations of things to specific consuming types.)